# How do I check phone numbers in MongoDB collection for equivalence using node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I tried to write such a function by myself, yet I've encountered a problem:

```
router.get('/:number', async (req, res) => {
    const number = req.params.number
    try {
        await User.find({'phone': number})
        .then((result) => {
            if (result != Array) {
                res.send(response1)
            } else {
                res.send(response2)
            }
        })
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({ message: error })
    }
})
```

This code firstly receives the number that is needed to be checked, then it cycles through the MongoDB collection in search of the following type of record `{'phone': number}`. As a result, the function should return an object if the number exists in the database, if not - it should return null. Depending on this, the function should execute response1 or response2. BUT, because of some reason (which I do not know yet), it just returns the response1 no matter the result.

Comment: what is response1, response2 here, I am not seeing any initialization of it, you should return result or null.

Comment: The `find`returns a _cursor_.  You need to read the cursor to get the documents. Or, you can use the `findOne` method which returns a document (if it exists) else a `null`.

Comment: just a side note, it is a good idea to adopt a strict REST API pattern like https://jsonapi.org/ or https://www.narwhl.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

close!

```js
router.get('/:number', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { number } = req.params
        // users will always return an array
        const users = await User.find({ phone: number })
        res.send(users[0]) // returning index 0 will either return the record if it exists, or it will return null
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({ message: error })
    }
})
```

also, Javascript will not respond the way you think if you say `users !== Array` the correct syntax is `!Array.isArray(users)`, hence why it was always running, because the response is never equal to class `Array` how you had it written

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray